# Magento 2.4.4-2.4.5 - {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}

Tags: magento2, email-templates

Magento 2.4.4 + 2.4.5 has made changes to Email templates:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/email-migration/

I'm working on the upgrade to 2.4.5 and this depend section is no longer working:

```
{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
   <div class="ampdf-address-section-item">
       <p class="ampdf-title ampdf-text">{{trans "Shipping Address"}}</p>
       <p class="ampdf-text">{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
   </div>
{{/depend}}
```

How do I translate this into the new 2.4.4-2.4.5 requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Magento 2.4.5, email template format is change. So please check the below condition

```
{{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
   <div class="ampdf-address-section-item">
       <p class="ampdf-title ampdf-text">{{trans "Shipping Address"}}</p>
       <p class="ampdf-text">{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
   </div>
{{/depend}}
```

I hope it will help you. If any issue let me know.

Comment: Yup it works, thanks! I just wish I didnt have to guess what the syntax is. If they wrote it all out in documentation, that would be great.